# Error when launching Ubuntu for the first time on Windows10

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I launched Ubuntu for the first time, I got an error that said

> 0x8000000d an illegal state change was requested

I have already enabled the Windows Subsystem for Linux.
How do I resolve this issue?.